# python serial returns random ascii

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am using python on an nvidia tegra's serial port to create a simple serial connection to an arduino I am trying to pass through integers and strings but they are getting cut off.

my code looks something like this

```
ser = serial.Serial(
port=/dev/ttyS0,
baudrate=9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)
print ser.isOpen()  
ser.write("hello\n")
```

this is returning h▒▒▒▒,
when i try integers it will only return integers 2,4,7,8 otherwise it is ▒
if i try doing something like ser.write(str("hello")) i get more random characters, is it somehow encoded differently is there a way just to read it normally?

Comment: Do you have the correct settings on the receiving end? I see that you use Parity for example. Is that turned on on the receiving end?

Comment: @JacobPålsson not very familiar with parity, on the receiving end I am just using an arduino serial.read() so I am guessing it is not on

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) bit in the python code since that might not be enabled at the receiving Arduino.

The resulting code would be:

```
ser = serial.Serial(
port=/dev/ttyS0,
baudrate=9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)
print ser.isOpen()  
ser.write("hello\n")
```

**Or** when you start your serial communication on the Arduino, you add odd parity in the configuration parameter as below:

```
Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8O1)
```

That will start serial communication with baudrate 9600, 8 data bits, odd parity bit and one stop bit.

Comment: Thanks, cant try it now but ill see if this works tomorrow